# How to turn a list of Int into a list of tuples representing consecutive ranges

Tags: haskell

I would like to turn a list like this

```
[0,10,100,500,1000,5000]
```

into a list of tuples representing consecutive ranges like this:

```
[(0,10),(10,100),(100,500),(500,1000),(1000,5000)]
```

Is there a compact way to do this in Haskell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure:

```
fn :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
fn xs = zip xs (tail xs)

Prelude> fn [0, 10, 100, 500]
[(0,10),(10,100),(100,500)]
```

Comment: Isn't `zipWith (,)` just `zip`?

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty compact:

```
consecutivePairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
consecutivePairs [] = []
consecutivePairs [_] = []
consecutivePairs (x:xs@(y:_)) = (x, y) : consecutivePairs xs
```